# Custom Report #googleanalytics regular expressions

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a report in google analytics which should include this `/customer/account/create?signup=1&invitation_url` as a part of the landing page. When I create the custom report for filters when I add
`/customer/account/create?signup=1&invitation_url` and use regex I am getting null values. What regex expression can I use to get this?

Basically I need all sessions from the landing page that includes
`/customer/account/create?signup=1&invitation_url`

Answer (score 0):

You need to screen special symbols with "\".

`\/customer\/account\/create\?signup=1&invitation_url`

Good tool to test regex:
https://regex101.com/